# Плагин загрузки файлов Ajax - вопрос по domready

Tags: javascript

Использую плагин: https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader
В документации написано, что инициализацию плагина произвести после полной загрузки DOM.
Стало быть в контейнере:

```
$(function () { });
```

Но как быть, если DOM создается JS динамически? В таком случае событие:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({...
```

уже не срабатывает, так как контейнер #fileupload был создан динамически

Comment: А пробовали инициализировать плагин после того, как контейнер будет создан? Создать что-то, если не предусмотренно, наподобие callback-функции.

Comment: Если засунуть инициализацию плагина в функцию и функцию вызывать как callback, то не работает, так как инициализация должны быть в :

     $(function () { });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Oleg Ponomarchuk](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk)](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk), Что "если" или "куда засунуть" - меня не убеждают. Я спрашивал вас о том, пробовали ли вы или нет. Похоже, что нет. Ладно, давайте [я за вас попробую](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/H6tEQ/).